# Can't get windows task scheduler to run scheduled console application

Tags: batch-file, dos, bcp, scheduled-tasks

I have a console app that uses two batch files to decompress a zip file, take the xls which was decompressed convert it to CSV and BCP the data into a SQL table. I'd like to schedule this console app to run once a day. I set up windows task scheduler to run said app. I try to "test run" the task and don't get an error. I have the app writing to a txt file when exceptions are caught and i get an error along the lines of "the xls file you are trying to use is being used by another process".

NOTE: I know there are more efficiant ways of accomplishing the importation of xls to SQL, but it is for a client who is too cheap to buy a FULL version of SQL SERVER.

Comment: The first batch file runs using 7zip (7z.exe x C:\BCP\RFSR.zip -aoa -oC:\BCP\ -ppassword)
del c:\BCP\RFSR.csv*.* /q

Comment: the second batch uses BCP to copy a CSV into a SQL DB.
(bcp server.dbo.test in c:\BCP\RFSR.csv -F2 -t, -c -S server -U username -P password)

Answer (score 1):

Something hasn't released it's hold on the XML file.  You need to figure out what other program is using that resource and ensure that it's connections are closed.  It could be that in your test run you don't close your connection, and then later on when the task is run, there's another process (the earlier instance of your app) that hasn't released the resource.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you are triying to use the xml file before it's fully decompressed. Also check the possibility that rie819 mentioned before.

We could help you better if you post your scripts.

Comment: Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
    Dim currentDir As String = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString
    Sub main()
        callRFSRDecompressBatch()
        ExcelToCVS()
        callBCPCSVBatch()
    End Sub

Comment: Sub ExcelToCVS()
        Dim StrConn As String
        Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        Dim Str As String
        Dim ColumnCount As Integer
        Dim OuterCount As Integer
        Dim InnerCount As Integer
        Dim RowCount As Integer
   Try
 StrConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\BCP\RFSR.XLS;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

Comment: Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(StrConn)
            Try
                objConn.Open()
                If objConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                Else
                    End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                logError(ex)
                Exit Sub
            End Try
            Dim objCmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [rfsr$]", objConn)
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim ObjStreamWriter As StreamWriter
            ObjStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("c:\BCP\RFSR.CSV")

Comment: Try
                DA.SelectCommand = objCmd
                DA.Fill(DS, "XLData")
            Catch ex As Exception
                logError(ex)
            End Try
            RowCount = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            ColumnCount = DS.Tables(0).Columns.Count
Str = ""
            For i As Integer = 0 To ColumnCount - 1
                Str &= DS.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName & ","
            Next
            ObjStreamWriter.WriteLine(Str)

Comment: For OuterCount = 0 To RowCount - 1
                Str = ""
                For InnerCount = 0 To ColumnCount - 1
                    If DS.Tables(0).Rows(OuterCount).Item(InnerCount).ToString.Contains(",") Then
Str &= DS.Tables(0).Rows(OuterCount).Item(InnerCount).ToString.Replace(",", ".")
                        Str &= ","
                    Else
                        Str &= DS.Tables(0).Rows(OuterCount).Item(InnerCount) & ","
                    End If

                Next
                'Str &= ","
                ObjStreamWriter.WriteLine(Str)
            Next

Comment: ObjStreamWriter.WriteLine(Str)
            Next
            ObjStreamWriter.Close()
            Try
            Catch ex As Exception
                logError(ex)
            End Try
            objCmd.Dispose()
            objCmd = Nothing
            objConn.Close()
            objConn.Dispose()
            objConn = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            logError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
 Public Sub callBCPCSVBatch()
        Try
Dim targetDir As String
 Dim p As New Process
 p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
 targetDir = "C:\BCP\"

Comment: p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "BCPCSV.bat"
            p.Start()
p.WaitForExit()
deleteXLS()
 Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill()
  Public Sub callRFSRDecompressBatch()
        Try
Dim targetDir As String
            Dim p As New Process
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

Comment: targetDir = currentDir + "\Filez"
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "RFSRDecompress.bat"
            p.Start()
            p.WaitForExit()
 Catch ex As Exception
            logError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
Public Sub logError(ByVal ex)
 Dim SW As New StreamWriter("c:\BCP\BCPErrorLog.txt")
        SW.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        SW.Close()
    End Sub
End Module

Comment: The code for the two DOS batch files are in the comments section of my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to produce the results I needed. I took the two batch files out of the console app. I now have a task scheduled to run one batch, the console app, and the last batch. Both answers I recieved were correct, it wasn't releasing the XML because of the console windows opening in the middle of execution. Since they have been removed I no longer have errors. Thanks for the help. -Z